# sendUserActionEvent() mView is null

Tags: android

After switching from one activity to other when again come back to previous activity app crashed.It is only happens on samsung devices like samsung tab 3.
Log cat show **sendUserActionEvent() mView == null**

Comment: You are testing it on Samsung S4?

Comment: Just ignore that error

Comment: @Amy No,I am testing it on samsung tab 3.But it is working smoothly on sony and motorola devices.

Comment: @Amy but this error crash my application every time.Does it happens on every samsung devices.

Comment: this is not a problem related to your code, but related to some Samsung devices

Answer (score 0):

The android clear the invisible activity when some other process need more memory then it will kill the activity and interacted memory .

you can ignore this issue .
happy coding

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this message is because when the S4 returns to your app it does not find the view any more. It is a bug in S4 and will not occur in newer devices. I found a workaround by declaring the views as global static variables in the activity class. This way they will be found. I know it is not good practise to use global static variables. It solved the problem on the S4, though.